# predefined input in a nohup shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, nohup

i am trying to write a shell script that i can then `nohup` as it is supposed to run for hours. i am a shell novice so I'm struggling with it a lot.

the script should first open some software (ACE data mining suite), which usually prompts the user for some input (choosing one of many possible input files; this can potentially be avoided by only placing one input file in the directory from which the script is called). i then need to start the algorithm by typing its name in (`warmr`). 
in summary I need the script to: 
1) open ACE
2) input file name into ACE (optional, can be avoided) 
3) start the algorithm by inputting its name

input in steps 2-3 should be predefined -- i do not want to be prompted for it as i know what i want to run.

so far i have `ace_script`:

```
#!/bin/sh

/home/nfg/ACE-ilProlog-1.2.20/linux/bin/ace
```

adding `echo "warmr"` or `read "warmr"` avails to nothing. running `ace_script` fires up ACE which then complains of an error reading from the stream and shuts down.

Comment: Put the input it is expecting into a file `aceinput`, and append `<aceinput` to the command?

Comment: @JeffY thanks a lot! it works as intended. but only if i avoid step 2. i think this is because ACE is not fully initiated unless a settings file is chosen at step 2. but that's okay because, like i said, i can avoid it and step 3 works perfectly with your suggestion. again, many thanks!